# File merging - same name, different extension

Tags: files, cat, merge

How would you merge different input .txt and .tsv files (within a directory) who have the same name but a different extension into an output file?

---

Input: `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file1.tsv`, `file2.tsv`

Output: `file1.merged`, `file2.merged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
ext='(txt|tsv|text|log)'
for f (**/*.$~ext(.)) cat < $f >> $f:t:r.merged
```

The order of merging will be alphabetical within a same directory. That is, `a/file.txt` will be included before `b/file.txt` and `a/file.log` before `a/file.txt`.

Also note that hidden files (those whose name starts with `.`) won't be considered (add the `D` glob qualifier if you want them).

Answer (score 1):

`cat file1.* > file1.merged`

`cat file2.* > file2.merged`

Comment: Yes but, I don't have only two extensions per file name (There could be for example something like `file1.csv` that I'm not willing to merge). Plus, I have a lot of filenames (~100), so a loop would be better.

Comment: Exactly, @don_crissti, that's my point.

Comment: The question says that you're looking to merge all files with the same name but different extension into an output file.  This means that if you have a file1.csv in the same directory, it will be merged into the output file.  If only *.txt and *.tsv are allowed, then you can instead do `cat file1.txt file1.tsv > file1.merged && cat file2.txt file2.tsv > file2.merged`  As for multiple filenames, you may want to write a script to handle the matrix of which files should be concatenated and which should not.

Comment: Yes, good point.  I will edit the question. By the way, I need a loop to look for filenames, I cannot concatenate manually.